# i am trying to load view pages in a single function

Tags: php, codeigniter

**this is one of my view pages....of links**

```
 <a href="<?php echo  base_url('general/company/balancesheet');?>">SHEET</a>
 <a href="<?php echo  base_url('general/company/cashflow'); ?>">CASH FLOW</a>
 <a href="<?php echo  base_url('general/');     ?>">DOCUMENTS</a>
```

and i have the view pages of the specified link in my directory,i just wan't to load these pages on my controller like this.its not working
controller.....

```
public function company(){
if(base_url('general/company/balancesheet'))
 {
   $this->load->view('index');
   $this->load->view('staff/gst_client/company/BalanceSheet');
 }
if(base_url('general/company/cashflow'))
 {
   $this->load->view('index');
   $this->load->view('staff/gst_client/company/cashflow');
 }
```

etc
how can we use a single function of condition to route the views in stead of creating separate function like this

```
public function balacesheet(){
 $this->load->view('index');
 $this->load->view('staff/gst_client/company/BalanceSheet');
}
public function cashflow(){
 $this->load->view('index');
 $this->load->view('staff/gst_client/company/cashflow');
}
```

Comment: Why would you want that? Your code will be better structured if each route has it's own controller method. If they are all in the same method, it will just grow and become a mess if you need to add some logic to a couple of the routes.